# My loop keeps repeating same value when I want it to change with each instance

Tags: python, loops, oop, while-loop

Recently I've been tasked with creating a sort of game, where you have two objects (e.g. airplane1, airplane2) which are a part of a class called "Airplanes"

The Airplanes class is supposed to have a method called "shoot" which is supposed to accept objects of the class as its parameters. The method takes away a random amount of hp from the enemy and takes away double the random amount of health from the shooter, this is supposed to happen until one of the airplanes has 0 hp. I have everything in order, except my while loop keeps printing the same amount of ammo and health throughout all the 10 instances and it can never get down to 0, because it always keeps the value of the first instance.

```
import random

class Airplane:
    def __init__(self, name, maxHp, maxAmmo,):
        self.name = name
        self.maxHp = maxHp
        self.hp = maxHp
        self.maxAmmo = maxAmmo
        self.ammo = maxAmmo

    def shoot(self, target):
        randomAmt = random.randrange(10, 25)
        damage = randomAmt
        target.hp = target.maxHp - damage
        self.ammo = self.maxAmmo - damage * 2
        counter = 1
        while counter <= 10:
            print(f"{counter}    {self.name} │ {self.maxAmmo}/{self.ammo} │ {self.maxHp}/{self.hp}  :  {target.name} │ {target.maxAmmo}/{target.ammo} │ {target.maxHp}/{target.hp}")
            counter+=1    
            
            
plane1 = Airplane(input("Enter name: "), 100, 250)
plane2 = Airplane(input("Enter name: "), 100, 250)


print(plane1.shoot(plane2))
```

Comment: you are not doing anything in the while loop except printing something to the screen and incrementing a number, you aren't really updating the values you are printing inside the loop.

Comment: why you the 'demge is from the max and not from the current hp. and the while just print the same value. did you mean to print 10 shoots?

Answer (score 2):

You have called the `shoot` method once in your code.
The loop in the `shoot` method only prints the same info every time because that's what the code is written to do. Your loop does not retrigger shooting.
Two options:

- Move the while loop outside the class to call the `shoot` method multiple times.
- Alternatively, after the print statement in the loop, call the `self.shoot` to retrigger shooting.

Answer (score 1):

take this sample but, add a STOP condition when self.hp get to 0

```
import random

counter = 1

class Airplane:
    def __init__(self, name, maxHp, maxAmmo,):
        self.name = name
        self.maxHp = maxHp
        self.hp = maxHp
        self.maxAmmo = maxAmmo
        self.ammo = maxAmmo

    def shoot(self, target):
        randomAmt = random.randrange(10, 25)
        damage = randomAmt
        target.hp = target.hp - damage
        self.ammo = self.ammo - damage * 2
        print(f"{counter}    {self.name} │ {self.maxAmmo}/{self.ammo} │ {self.maxHp}/{self.hp}  :  {target.name} │ {target.maxAmmo}/{target.ammo} │ {target.maxHp}/{target.hp}")


plane1 = Airplane(input("Enter name: "), 100, 250)
plane2 = Airplane(input("Enter name: "), 100, 250)


while counter <= 10:
    plane1.shoot(plane2)
    counter+=1
```